# Docker compose environment variable is not set

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In my docker-compose.yml I set the environment variable PORTUNIQUE but it tells me that the env variable isn't set.

```
version: "3"

services:
    gateway-service:
      build: ./
      environment: 
        - PORTUNIQUE=8686
      ports:
        - ${PORTUNIQUE}:${PORTUNIQUE}
```

If I however use a .env file with the following content, it works fine:

`PORTUNIQUE=3000`

> WARNING: The PORTUNIQUE variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank
> string.

Comment: Watch out for indentation when using yaml. It actually doesn't work if you are not careful. first ones in your file have 4 spaces and the next ones have 2.

Comment: I think the problem is that variables that you set with environment are only available INSIDE of the container, not within the docker-compose.yml. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62519283/5688490

Comment: @Mick, the documentation on [https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file) says otherwise. The vars **are** available in the docker-compose file itself.

Comment: I have the same issue. The documentation clearly says variables declared in environment config should be available in the container: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#set-environment-variables-in-containers. But it does not seem to be the case.