# Failed to read environment variables from the file declared in env_file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

In my docker-compose.yml, I defined two services, `app` and `db`.

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  app:
    image: my_app
    container_name: my-app
    ports:
      - ${MY_PORT}:${MY_PORT}
    env_file:
      - ./app.env
    ...
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=${DB_URL}
  db:
    image: my_db
    container_name: my-db
    env_file:
      - ./db.env
    ports:
      - ${DB_PORT}:${DB_PORT}
```

As you can see above, I have defined two env files, `app.env` and `db.env` in the `env_file` option of `app` and `db` services.

app.env:

```sh
MY_PORT=8081
```

db.env:

```sh
DB_PORT=4040
DB_URL=postgres://myapp:app@db:4040/myapp
```

I want to check if my docker-compose can successfully read the environment variables. So, I run the command `docker-compose config`. However the output is

```sh
$ docker-compose config
WARNING: The MY_PORT variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The DB_URL variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The DB_PORT variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.app.ports is invalid: Invalid port ":", should be [[remote_ip:]remote_port[-remote_port]:]port[/protocol]
services.db.ports is invalid: Invalid port ":", should be [[remote_ip:]remote_port[-remote_port]:]port[/protocol]
```

Why my docker compose can't read environment variables from those env files I declared in the `env_file` option in my docker-compose.yml?

Besides, I have another question, that's I understand that normally the env file shouldn't be version controlled since it could contain credentials. How normally should the env file be used for different environment e.g. development, staging and production environments? Imaging different environment has different values for those variables. Could someone please provide some examples?

Comment: can you change the version "1" to version "3.7"  with docker engine 18.06.0+ and recheck

Comment: Changed, same issue.

Answer (score 7):

The reason this is failing, is that the environment variables that you are defining the the external named `app.env` and `db.env` files, and specifying in the `env_file` option, are only being set inside the container that is started - and are not used for variable expansion inside the `docker-compose.yml` file when parsed by docker-compose.

This is easily confused with the option of supplying a file named `.env` in the same location as the `docker-compose.yml` file. Since docker-compose will look for a file specifically named `.env` next to the `docker-compose.yml` file (or next to the file that you are specifying with the `-f` switch) - and use the environment variables in that file for variable expansion in the `docker-compose.yml` file, before parsing it.

In other words:

### The `env_file` option

- Will set environment variables inside your container, is is just a convenience feature that allows you to externalise the environment variables from the `docker-compose.yml` file
- Environment variables in these files will **NOT** be used for variable expansion in the `docker-compose.yml` file before parsed by docker-compose.

### The `.env` file

- Will be used for environment variable expansion inside the `docker-compose.yml` file before parsing.
- Will **NOT** set environment variables inside the started container.

### Suggested solution to the first question

If you migrate your values into a single `.env` file and place it in the same directory as your `docker-compose.yml` file, this should work.

### Second question

As I understand your second question, you are asking how the `.env` file, or the `env_file` option should be used to configure your services for your different environments.

I do not think that there is a simple and single answer to this. It can be solved in a number of ways. But it also depends on what you are deploying to? Is it kubernetes? Docker swarm? Or just a single node docker host?

Kubernetes and Docker swarm have different means of helping you out with this.

- [Kubernetes secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/)
- [Docker swarm secrets](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/)

Those are highly secure solutions, where operators of the secrets can be limited, and the secrets will not be seen by developers or operators that do not have access.

But for the single node docker host, not operating in swarm mode (secrets only work in swarm mode), there really isn't a lot of fancy options. You will have to manage this pretty manually in your build and deploy pipes as far as I am aware.

You are right that the sensitive configuration of your services, should not go in the same repository as the service definition. Things like root password for a database, or credentials to your service discovery service for your production environment do not need to live next to the sources.

Traditionally, another repository would contain this - giving you the oppotunity to limit the group of people that have this access. The build/deployment server/service will check out the new revision of your service, build it perhaps, and then check out the configuration repository and start the services with the configurations from there. And, make sure to remove the configuration files afterwards.

That would be the solution I would recommend for a single node docker host deployment regime - two repositories, and some scripting that ensures that the correct .env file is put in place during deployment, and removed again.

I hope this is helpful?

Comment: Thanks. I understand the use of `.env` actually that was my original solution, then I would like to have a external file like .env but for different environments e.g. staging, production, that's why I changed to how it is now. But could you please provide an answer for my 2nd question in my post?

Comment: I know exactly what you mean - I was trying to do this at one point. It would seem like a really good feature for docker-compose to support. Right now I have to configure environments in other ways. I cleaned up the answer a bit - and I will address your other question in another edit in a moment.

Comment: I posted my thoughts and insights concerning the second question (which really should have been put in a question of its own somehow) - but perhaps you could tell me what your hosting solution looks like? Is it an experimental single host setup? And you are just trying to "do things the right way to learn"? Or is it something else?

Comment: Thanks! It is a single host, no swarm mode required in my project. Your suggestion makes sense :)  You said that the sensitive configurations e.g. database username password `Traditionally, another repository would contain this`, hmm...I noticed on internet some people suggest not having them be on the internet at all, that's don't version control it in any repo for the sake of security, do you feel that is a less traditional solution?

Comment: I personally like to have everything that makes up my setup defined in files that are controlled by a source control management system. This way, I can recreate my stacks from nothing at any given time. I consider it a resilience measure. I would like to emphasize the a git repository does not have to reside on a remote server - you could just create a repository on the local server, or a nearby server on the same private network. I do not think that just leaving the files uncontrolled on the deployment server is a great idea. If you loose them, then what? (continuing in next comment)

Comment: And when you want to modify them with changes - and the changes don't work out. How will you safely roll back?

Comment: Please consider a vote, or marking the answer as correct, if this was the answer to your question.