# Child environment variable does not get setup properly, why?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I have a "main" Docker project which triggers some child projects trhough the main `docker-compose.yml` and `.env` file. See the following directory structure so you can get a better idea:

```
`-- project/
    `-- docker-compose.yml/
        |-- .env
        |-- project-1/
        |   |-- docker-compose.yml
        |   `-- .env
        `-- project-2/
            |-- docker-compose.yml
            `-- .env
```

The main `.env` file (`/project/.env`) looks as follow:

```
COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1
COMPOSE_PATH_SEPARATOR=|
COMPOSE_FILE=docker-compose.local.yml|project-1/docker-compose.yml|project-2/docker-compose.yml
```

That tells Docker to run also those child `project-1, project-2` through it is `docker-compose.yml` and it is `.env` files.

I would like to have a custom configuration per project so I have added the following configuration to the child projects (`/project-1/docker-compose.yml, /project-2/docker-compose.yml`):

```
version: "2.4"
services:
  main-project-1:
    environment:
      - XDEBUG_MODE=${XDEBUG_MODE:-off}
```

If I am not wrong that means: if the variable `XDEBUG_MODE` is not defined then default it to `off` otherwise use the value defined in the `.env` file. Then I have configured the `.env` files as follow:

```
// project-2/.env
XDEBUG_MODE=on
```

For some reason, the environment variable `XDEBUG_MODE` gets set to `off` even if I am setting it to `debug` in the `.env` file.

I have tried also the following:

```
version: "2.4"
services:
  main-project-1:
    environment:
      - XDEBUG_MODE=${XDEBUG_MODE}
```

But again it is set to `off`.

I do not want to define the variable in the main `.env` file because I want to give the ability to set it on/off per project. What I could be missing here?

I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62518965/failed-to-read-environment-variables-from-the-file-declared-in-env-file/62519283#62519283) among other's posts on the Internet but can not find a solution to my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstand how `docker-compose` find `.env`, see [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/):

> Compose supports declaring default environment variables in an environment file named .env placed in the folder where the docker-compose command is executed (current working directory).

That means it try to find the `.env` in the folder where you run `docker-compose` command, not the folder where you store `docker-compose.yaml`.

Next to prove it:

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  app1:
    image: ubuntu:16.04
    environment:
      - XDEBUG_MODE=${XDEBUG_MODE:-off}
```

**.env:**

```
XDEBUG_MODE=on
```

- if you run `docker-compose config` in current folder, it will show:

  ```
  services:
    app1:
      environment:
        XDEBUG_MODE: "on"
      image: ubuntu:16.04
  version: '3.0'
  ```
- if you run `docker-compose -f 20210108/docker-compose.yaml config` in its parent folder (Suppose its parent folder is 20200108), then it will show:

  ```
  services:
    app1:
      environment:
        XDEBUG_MODE: "off"
      image: ubuntu:16.04
  version: '3.0'
  ```

**Finally**, for your case, the correct way is next:

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  app1:
    image: ubuntu:16.04
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    command: ["env"]
    environment:
      - XDEBUG_MODE=${XDEBUG_MODE:-off}
```

**.env:**

```
COMPOSE_PATH_SEPARATOR=|
COMPOSE_FILE=docker-compose.yaml|project1/docker-compose.yaml
```

**project1/docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  app2:
    image: ubuntu:16.04
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    command: ["env"]
    env_file: project1/.env
```

**project1/.env**:

```
XDEBUG_MODE=on
```

**The output:**

```
$ docker-compose config
services:
  app1:
    command:
    - env
    environment:
      XDEBUG_MODE: "off"
    image: ubuntu:16.04
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
  app2:
    command:
    - env
    environment:
      XDEBUG_MODE: "on"
    image: ubuntu:16.04
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
version: '3.0'
```

**NOTE**: for `project1/docker-compose.yaml`, you should delete next, the variables in `env_file` will directly be used by container, and will not expand if you define same variable in `environment`. In fact it not to redefine the path of `.env`, just let `env_file` to reuse the variable in `.env`:

```
environment:
  - XDEBUG_MODE=${XDEBUG_MODE:-off}
```

Comment: just one doubt remaining, how do I use environment variables defined in the main `.env` file at `project-1/docker-compose.yml`? Since I will be redefining the env file in that child project I will still be able to use the environment variables from the main `.env` file inside that child docker container?

Comment: You could still use `environment:
  - ABC=${ABC}` to refers the other variable in main .env. In fact, docker-compose will combine all `docker-compose.yaml` defined, so the next level compose file still could access main .env. `docker-compose config` is the internal result how it finally look like.